# blender 2.9 ui glitched?

Tags: versions

I just downloaded version 2.9 on my 2010 macbook pro, but all the UI seems to be glitched out. Any UI element that should have a box outline only has a triangle (see picture I don't know how to describe it correctly). Its still usable despite this but its hard to read some of the ui. does anyone know how to fix this?[image]

Comment: Make sure that your system meets at least the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) to run blender and that your drivers are up to date. Graphical issues are almost always GPU problems.

Comment: problems displaying the interface are related to the GPU, get the latest drivers.

Comment: In order to run Blender 2.90 you need macOS 10.13 or later. Nvidia GPUs have to be from the Nvidia GeForce 400 series or later. AMD GPUs have to have the [GCN first generation micro-architecture or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview). More information can be found in the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender.